# Incorrect location is shown when a KML file is imported into Google Maps

Tags: java, maps, kml

I have a program that generates a KML File automatically. However, when Import it into Google maps, it takes me somewhere else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>Google Maps - Evidence File</name>
<description>Cheltenham</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>51°54'51.94116", -2°6'8.12088"</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

I've double checked the coordinates. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinates are in wrong format, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language or https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?hl=fi#coordinates for correct format.

You are using format degrees minutes seconds, should be decimal degrees. And assuming you mean [Cheltenham, UK](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Cheltenham&hl=en&ll=51.895775,-2.074184&spn=0.062288,0.14883&hnear=Cheltenham,+Gloucestershire,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=13), they need to be in the order longitude,latitude (no spaces). Correct format in KML would be `<coordinates>-2.1022558,51.9144281</coordinates>`.